# Parse xml to extract the contents between div using Python

Tags: python, html, xml, xml-parsing

```
I have the below data which is stored in a string. It resembles xml. Is there a way that I can extract the contents of div class "page" and extract all the text under it?
```

Started with the below code. However tree.text returns None.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET   
xml = ET.fromstring(str_content)  
for tree in xml:    
        print(tree.text)



  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <body><div class="page"><p />
    <p>Hi This is the content to be parsed!!! 
    Extract the text. 
    Done </p>
    <p />
    </div>
    <div class="page"><p />
    <p>Hi This is the content to be parsed!!! 
    Extract the text. 
    Done </p>
    <p />
    </div>
    </body></html>

Sample input and output for multiple <p> within div:

    <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'>
    <body><div class='page'><p />
    <p>Text in 1st line
    </p>
    <p>Text in 2nd line
    </p>
    <p>Text in 3rd line</p>
    <p />
    </div>
    <div class='page'><p />
    <p>Text in 1st line 2nd page
    </p>
    <p>© Text in 2nd line 2nd page
    </p>
    <p>Text in 3rd line 2nd page
    </p>
    <p>Text in 4th line 2nd page.
        Still in the same para.
        I want to preserve spaces and newlines
    </p>
    <p>etc 
        etc,
        ectc
    </p>
    <p>some info | 2018-11-09 1</p>
    <p />
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Output for the above:

### Page no.1...

Text in 1st lineText in 2nd lineText in 3rd line

### Page no.2...

Text in 1st line 2nd page© Text in 2nd line 2nd pageText in 3rd line 2nd pageText in 4th line 2nd page.
Still in the same para.
I want to preserve spaces and newlinesetc
etc,
ectcsome info | 2018-11-09 1

Comment: Content which I am trying to parse below:

Comment: Can `beautifulsoup` be used?

Comment: I don't mind using any library. I just want to extract the contents. Let me explore more on beautifulsoup. Would be great if you can share something if you have it handy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script uses `beautifulsoup` to locate the `<div>s` and extract the text from them.

`data` is the XML string from the question.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

for num, page in enumerate(soup.select('.page'), 1):
    print('Page no.{}...'.format(num))
    print('-' * 80)

    print(page.get_text(strip=True))

    print()
```

Prints:

```
Page no.1...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hi This is the content to be parsed!!!
    Extract the text.
    Done

Page no.2...
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Hi This is the content to be parsed!!!
    Extract the text.
    Done
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It works to a good extent. However I can have multiple <p> within a div. In such cases it is not maintaining any spaces between two difference <p> which is giving undesired output. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: @San Can you edit your question and put the code there? You can also use `print(page.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))`, where `separator=` is string that will separate tags

Comment: Sure would try this. Also added the code and output above

Comment: Thanks @Andrej. did a quick test and separator seems to work pretty much. Thanks for your immediate responses and quick help :)